# Angular 2 and Three.js

Tags: angular, three.js

So I've been attempting to implement THREE.js into my Angular 2 app.  I have not been able to successfully import the libraries into Angular 2.  There are a few projects that have outdated source code, that run with either Angular 2 (beta) or Angular js.  Right now I'd be ecstatic to have a blank project that runs THREE.js, from there I could start my directives.

If anyone knows of any good examples or pointers on how to add THREE.js to an angular 2 project, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Three.js into your Angular2 app in 2 steps:

1. add the library to your modules with `npm install three` command;
2. put `import * as THREE from 'three'` inside your component or service.

For typings support execute `npm install --save @types/three`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the angular-cli.json file so the 3 steps would be:

1. Add the library to your modules with `npm i three --save` command.
2. Include the library in the "angular-cli.json" file in the "scripts" area:

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "../node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
   ],
   ```
3. Put `declare var THREE:any;` at the top of your component or service.

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently fighting for days with three.js in Angular 5.2.9. I tried each way of importing three.js library into my project and here's what I found the best:

1. [Download three.js from official website](https://threejs.org/)
2. Use .js files from ***build*** folder (I went with *three.min.js*)
3. You can also find additional methods in ***src*** folder (eg. *CSS3DRenderer*)
4. Put those files into your project (I have them in ./assets/libraries/
5. Import the scripts in index.html after opening of body tag.
6. Define THREE in typings.d.ts: `declare var THREE: any;`
7. You can also `npm install @types/three` to get additional typings support.

This is the only way I managed to get all the methods I wanted working. If you want only basic Three.js methods then installing the library through npm will be just fine. However I needed CSS3DRenderer and so this the only way that worked for me.